# How to add a new column in r dataframe with a constant number?

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I create a new column containing a constant value like 100?

Example:
Number
100
100
100
100

Comment: `df1$Number <- 100` (it will recycle to replicate the same value)

Comment: Thank you! And how can I create a new data frame without affecting the original one?

Comment: `transform(df1, Number = 100)`

Answer (score 9):

With `dplyr`, you can use `mutate` and assign a constant number to a new variable. If you only provide one number (like 100 below), then each row will be filled in with that given number.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(newCol = 100)
```

**Output**

```
    x newCol
1   1    100
2   2    100
3   3    100
4   4    100
5   5    100
6   6    100
7   7    100
8   8    100
9   9    100
10 10    100
```

Or in base R, you can create a copy of the dataframe, then create the new column:

```
df2 <- df
df2$Number <- 100
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:10))
```